# Есть ли курсы по созданию визуальной новеллы на java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, разработка-игр

Изучаю разработку приложений под Android на java, решил создать собственную визуальную новеллу, в связи с этим у меня вопрос, есть ли какие нибудь курсы (может быть книги) на эту тематику?

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем ответ, но все же

1. Я бы порекомндовал задать этот вопрос на английском so. Если такие
   книги существуют, не велика вероятность что они переведенны на
   русский
2. Не привязывайтесь к Java. Вряд ли кто-то делает подобные вещи на "нативном" андроиде, потому она вам может просто не пригодиться. Скорее тут нужны движки. Нарпимер тот же Unity. Имеет относительно невысокий порог вхождения и явно будет поудобнее для ваших нужд, чем попытки создать свой движок на родных андроидовских вьюшках

Comment: На en.SO такой вопрос очень быстро закроют, т.к. рекомендации ресурсов — оффтопик.

Comment: Тоже верно, но мало ли. So не без добрыйх людей) Плюс с этим можно пойти не на overflow, а на какой-нибудь геймдев или еще куда

Comment: Для новелл рекомендую использовать движок **RenPy**, он как раз поддерживает платформу Android. Если хотите писать что то сложное на нем то требуется изучить яп Python. Довольно распространен для визуальных новелл, поэтому курсов довольно много.